# Mongodb won't start in Docker container when remote-mounting a volume from host

Tags: mongodb, docker

On a Mac, I'm running mongodb from docker with the data directory mounted from a volume on my host like this:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v /Users/me/git/world/db:/var/lib/mongodb gzoller/world
```

(/var/lib/mongodb is where the mongo config file says its storing data.)

I want to have my data persist on the host even if I kill the container running mongodb.

Using this run command tho, mongo doesn't start in the container.  The mongo log in the container has this clip:

```
Mon Sep 14 18:27:59 [initandlisten] options: { command: [ "run" ], config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: "true", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log", unixSocketPrefix: "/var/run/mongodb" }
Mon Sep 14 18:27:59 [initandlisten] Assertion: 13651:Couldn't fsync directory '/var/lib/mongodb': errno:22 Invalid argument
```

I've chmod a+rwx the db directory on the host I'm mounting to.

What I think I've learned so far is that (at least on a Mac) only root in the container can write to a volume on the host and mongo creates its own user, mongodb, which I presume can't write to my mounted volume.

How can I get mongo writing to a mounted host volume on MacOS?

Comment: I assume you use OSX and boot2docker?

Comment: OSX with Docker Machine

Comment: did you find a solution in the meantime? i;m having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Looks that's not permission issue. If review the origin repository ([gzoller/world/go.sh](https://github.com/gzoller/world/blob/master/go.sh#L2)), you should run the command as below:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -p 27017:27017 -p 28017:28017 -p 11211:11211 -v /Users/me/git/world/db:/var/lib/mongodb -e HOST_IP=`docker-machine ip default` gzoller/world
```

Let me know the result.

Comment: Mongo didn't start in the container.  Log had this: https://gist.github.com/gzoller/5ff4737e9aa1a55bd211.  The directory (db) on the host is chmod 777.

Comment: Oh, you are the owner of the repository `gzoller/world`